# Sending a value from a called macro back to a Cellref

Tags: excel, vba

This should be super simple but I cannot figure it out. What I am trying to do is have a loop run through 20 cells (F9:F29) and for each one that is populated, it is sending the value to another application to scan for data and determine if that value (an account number) is eligible to participate in a program. Thus, I need G9:G29 to return from the macro "Eligible" or "Not Eligible"

```vb
Public Sub Test() 

    Dim myRange As Range 
    Dim Counter As Integer  
    For Counter = 1 To 20         
        If Range("F8").Offset(Counter, 0) > 0 Then         
            Range("F8").Offset(Counter, 0).Select                  
            Call AccountEligible                  
        End If  
    Next Counter   
End Sub


Sub AccountEligible(Cellref as Range)
    
    Dim LastPageCheck As String
    Dim AccountCheck As String
    Dim AcctNumber As String
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim AcctType As String
    Dim FromDate As String
    Dim ToDate As String
    Dim Cusip As String
    
    Sheets("Starting Page").Activate
    FromDate = Range("I16").Value       'This assigns the from date in the search filter
    ToDate = Range("I17").Value
    Cusip = Range("I14").Value
    Account = Range(Cellref).Value
    
    
    ' ******** Check for Valid Class Action Data **********
    
    Sess0.ReadScreen NoDataChk, 1, iRow, 4          'check for no data in at all
    If NoDataChk = " " Then
        CellRef.Offset(, 1).Value = "Not Eligible"
        Exit Sub
    Else: CellRef.Offset(, 1).Value = "Eligible"
    End If
End Sub
```

Am I anywhere close on this? I cut out the middle code interacting with the program and just included the parts where I thought it would make a difference.

The code calling this macro is:

```
Public Sub Test() 
Dim myRange As Range 
Dim Counter As Integer  
For Counter = 1 To 20         

If Range("F8").Offset(Counter, 0) > 0 Then
Range("F8").Offset(Counter, 0).Select                  
Call AccountEligible                  
End If  

Next Counter            
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the specific problem you're having when you run this?  How are you calling this code?

Comment: Hey Tim, So I am trying to conceptualize this right now so I only wrote out the most basic version of this to start. IS the way I am using Cellref and Cellref.Offset(,1).Value appropriate? Essentially how I am calling it is:

```Public Sub Test()
Dim myRange As Range
Dim Counter As Integer

For Counter = 1 To 20
        If Range("F8").Offset(Counter, 0) > 0 Then
        Range("F8").Offset(Counter, 0).Select
        
        Call AccountEligible
        
        End If

Next Counter
     
    
End Sub```

Comment: To add code, please edit your question and place it there - too difficult to read in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make the check code into a function and just have it return the result:

```vb
Public Sub Test()
    Dim c As Range, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inputs") 'for example: I don't know what different sheets you're working with
    For Each c In ws.Range("F9:F29").Cells 'use an explcit sheet reference
        If c.Value > 0 Then
            c.Offset(0, 1).Value = AccountEligible(c.Value) 'call the function
        End If
    Next c
End Sub

'make this a Function
Function AccountEligible(Account) As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastPageCheck As String
    Dim AccountCheck As String
    Dim AcctNumber As String
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim AcctType As String
    Dim FromDate As String
    Dim ToDate As String
    Dim Cusip As String, NoDataChk
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Starting Page") 'use an explicit worksheet reference
    FromDate = ws.Range("I16").Value
    ToDate = ws.Range("I17").Value
    Cusip = ws.Range("I14").Value
    '  `Account` was passed in, so use that directly.... 
    
    
    ' ******** Check for Valid Class Action Data **********
    Sess0.ReadScreen NoDataChk, 1, iRow, 4          'check for no data in at all
    
    'return the result
    AccountEligible = IIf(NoDataChk = " ", "Not Eligible", "Eligible")
    
End Function
```

Comment: Hey there, that makes a lot of sense. The only piece I am still unclear on is for the function Cellref. Do I no longer need that? I do need to send the C values into a program in the function. Should I be doing:

```Account = c.value```

Comment: Sorry my bad - I wasn't able to test the code, so ended up making a mistake.  See update above - the calling code passes in the *value* of `c`, not the Range `c`.  I updated the function to use a parameter `Account` (the account name/id) instead of a Range object.

Comment: Thanks that helped there. This did produce a result I wasnt expecting. The Macro will not win the ```set sess0 = createobject("BZWHLL.WHLLobj")``` anymore. It wants me to define the object. It seems like a problem with doing it within a function. What it is doing is connecting to Attachmate Extra! to import data. Will I need to do it differently than a function to do that?

Comment: Upon further testing, it seems like within a function, non of the Attachmate inputs work. Is there a way to run this as a separate sub instead of a function?

Comment: Are you using `Option Explicit` - if yes then all variables need to be declared somewhere.